# How to incorporate hash inside hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

```
my %book = (
'name' => 'abc',
'author' => 'monk',
'isbn' => '123-890',
'issn' => '@issn',           
);

my %chapter = (
'title' => 'xyz',
'page' => '90',             
);
```

How do I incorporate %book inside %chapter through reference so that when I write "$chapter{name}", it should print 'abc'?

Comment: unmarked cross-post http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1045267

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can copy the keys/values of the `%book` into the `%chapter`:

   ```
   @chapter{keys %book} = values %book;
   ```

   Or something like

   ```
   %chapter = (%chapter, %book);
   ```

   Now you can `say $chapter{name}`, but changes in `%book` are not reflected in `%chapter`.
2. You can include the `%book` via reference:

   ```
   $chapter{book} = \%book;
   ```

   Now you could `say $chapter{book}{name}`, and changes do get reflected.

To have an interface that allows you to say `$chapter{name}` and that does reflect changes, some advanced techniques would have to be used (this is fairly trivial with [`tie` magic](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html)), but don't go there unless you *really* have to.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a subroutine to check a list of hashes for a key. This program demonstrates:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %book = (
  name   => 'abc',
  author => 'monk',
  isbn   => '123-890',
  issn   => '@issn',           
);

my %chapter = (
  title => 'xyz',
  page  => '90',             
);

for my $key (qw/ name title bogus / ) {
  print '>> ', access_hash($key, \%book, \%chapter), "\n";
}

sub access_hash {
  my $key = shift;
  for my $hash (@_) {
    return $hash->{$key} if exists $hash->{$key};
  }
  undef;
}
```

**output**

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at E:\Perl\source\ht.pl line 17.
>> abc
>> xyz
>>
```